# StackOverflow in iOS 6.1 when calling BecomeFirstResponder from inside TextFieldOnEditingDidEnd in

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I'm trying to be clever with my app.

I have 5 `UITextField` objects stacked on top of each other.  I want the user to be able to enter stuff in the first `UITextField` and then press 'Next' on the keypad and have focus move to the next `UITextField`.

My strategy for this was to have an array of `UITextField` objects and when `TextFieldOnEditingDidEnd` gets called, I would call '`BecomeFirstResponder()`' on the text field that appears AFTER the currently selected UITextField.

This strategy works fine on ios 7.x, however, it causes a STACK OVERFLOW in ios 6.

So, I am wondering if the fact that I call '`BecomeFirstResponder()`' is forcing `TextFieldOnEditDidEnd()` to be called on the text field that I just made into the first responder.

Does anybody have any idea if the call to `BecomeFirstResponder()` forces a call on `TextFieldOnEditDidEnd()` ?  Also, did this behavior change from iOS 6.x to iOS 7.x?

THANKS

Comment: `TextFieldOnEditDidEnd` was created by you, right?

Comment: OnEditDidEnd is the event that gets fired when user leaves the text field.  I just renamed it.

Comment: You've definitely created an infinite loop in iOS 6, and, if this doesn't happen in iOS 7, then yes, they changed the underlying architecture somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that will work on both iOS 6 and iOS 7 is to use delayed performance. In your `TextFieldOnEditingDidEnd`, do not call `becomeFirstResponder` directly; instead, call it inside a `dispatch_after` function call with a tiny delay. This will allow the first method to end before the second method starts, thus breaking the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answering your question, but another solution to this would be:

Set `tag`'s on the `textFields`. Starting form 1, 2, 3... Then, in the code, implement `textFieldShouldReturn:` like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIView * nextView = [textField.superview viewWithTag:textField.tag+1];
    if ([nextView respondsToSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)])
        [nextView becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```